# How do I delete entire lines in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that scrapes the raw html off of a webpage. When it does so, it has 17 lines at the top of the text file (output) that I want to be removed. How would one delete entire lines in powershell?

The generated lines are unique every time I run the script.

Current code:

```
$scrape = Invoke-Webrequest -uri "http://example.com/webpage"

$scrape.rawcontent | Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\outputlocation.txt -append
```

It then creates a file and gives me "stats" of the scraped webpage at the top of the file since it's the raw content. Deleting the first 17 lines would solve my issue.

Thanks!

Comment: If you just want to exclude output, you can skip X lines like `$scrape.rawcontent | Select -Skip 17  | Out-File ...`

Comment: @Cpt.Whale that would require a prior split I believe, `rawcontent` is a multi-line string, `$scrape.rawcontent -split '\r?\n' | ...`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Ah, totally right! split then skip

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Just curious, what does the '\r?\n' do? Also, would the command be $scrape.rawcontent -split '\r?\n' | Select -Skip 17 | Out-File ...  ?

Comment: @LordZeus splits the multi-line strings in newline / carriage return followed by newline. Yes the command would be as you have it there, thats fine

Comment: `$scrape.RawContent.Substring( ($scrape.RawContent.Length - $scrape.RawContentLength))`? Basically, number of _stat_ lines vary…

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding an intermediate cleanup step:

```
$scrape = Invoke-Webrequest -uri "http://example.com/webpage"
$scrape.RawContent|Out-File raw.txt 
Get-Content raw.txt| Select-Object -Skip 17 | 
        Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\outputlocation.txt -Append
```

Writing to file as scrape object may not contain the proper cr/lf combinations between lines.

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet (and its output)  shows that

- (the 1st column): **number of *"stats"* lines could differ from 17**,
- (the 2nd column): all HTML documents must start with a `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration, as well as how-to skip the *"stats"* lines (`$scrapeContent`), and
- (the 3rd column): computed `$scrapeContent` does not differ from `$scrape.Content`.

**The code:**

```
$urls = @(
    "https://example.com",
    "https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved",
    "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72561233",
    "https://stackoverflow.com/users/19112607/lordzeus"
)
if ( -not ( Get-Variable scrapes -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue )) {
    # computed conditionally to save tome and sources while debugging
    $scrapes = $urls |
        ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Url=$PSItem;
                HtmlWebResponseObj = Invoke-Webrequest -uri $PSItem
            }
        }
}
foreach ($aux in $scrapes) {
    $scrape = $aux.HtmlWebResponseObj
    $scrapeArray = $scrape.RawContent -split '\r?\n'
    # or           $scrape.RawContent -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
    $sDeclarationIndex = $scrapeArray.IndexOf(
        ($scrapeArray -match '^<!DOCTYPE')[0] )
    $scrapeContent = $scrape.RawContent.Substring(
        $scrape.RawContent.ToUpper().IndexOf('<!DOCTYPE'))
    # Write-Output
    (
        ( $sDeclarationIndex,
          ($scrapeContent -match '^<!DOCTYPE'),
          ($scrapeContent -eq $scrape.Content),
          $aux.Url
        ) -join ', '
    )
}
```

**Output**: `.\SO\72561233.ps1`

```
13, True, True, https://example.com
18, True, True, https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved
20, True, True, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72561233
21, True, True, https://stackoverflow.com/users/19112607/lordzeus
```